Create component through props in React
I have a component SomeComponent which takes a Component or IntrinsicElement through the component property and should construct that component. But this is giving type errors.

Parsing error: '>' expected.eslint
'Component' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Component'?ts(2749)
type Component = /unresolved/ any

Here is my source code and how I want it to be used:
import type { ElementType } from 'react';

function SomeComponent({ component: Component }: { component: ElementType }) {
  return (<Component />);
}

//
// This is how I want SomeComponent to be used:
//

const usage1 = <SomeComponent component="div" />;

function MyComponent() {
  return 123;
}

const usage2 = <SomeComponent component={MyComponent} />;

What am I doing wrong and how can this fixed?

Is it an eslint or a TS reported error? TS seems fine: https://tsplay.dev/mL0EVm

@ghybs Thank you. This put me in the right direction. My code was placed in a .ts file and not .tsx file. Changed that and it worked. Love you

It seems that tsc and/or ESLint treats <Component /> as a TypeScript type assertion (hence it expects > closing angle bracket, instead of the /> self closing tag end), instead of JSX syntax.
Make sure that these tools treat your code as JSX-enabled, usually with .tsx file extension.
